# Store Not binding data to View in Extjs 6 modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I am just creating a simple list example in modern area of the extjs 6.0.2 app, i crated the model, store and the view. After assigning the store to the list component it shows nothing to me in the view however i followed the instructions of Sencha docs.

Model => Task.js

```
Ext.define('NewsApp.model.Task', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
xtype:'Task',

fields: [
    { name: 'label',     type: 'string' },
    { name: 'done',      type: 'boolean', defaultValue:false }
]});
```

Store => Tasks.js

```
Ext.define('NewsApp.store.Tasks', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires:[
    'NewsApp.model.Task'
],

alias: 'store.tasks',

model: 'NewsApp.model.Task',

data : [
    {label: 'Make the bed'},
    {label: 'Go to Masjed'},
    {label: 'Take out the trash'},
    {label: 'Take Kids out'},
    {label: 'Go shopping'}
]});
```

View => about.js

```
Ext.define('NewsApp.view.about.About', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

requires: [
    'NewsApp.view.about.AboutController',
    'NewsApp.store.MobileOS',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'NewsApp.store.Tasks'
],
xtype: 'About',
controller: 'about',
fullscreen: true,
layout: 'vbox',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '<div class="todo-item">{label}</div>',
        store: 'NewsApp.store.Tasks',
        items: []
    }
]});
```

i also noticed a warning in the console while running tells me

> [WARN] The specified Store cannot be found

and i am sure i wrote the store name correctly in the list config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Store config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-modern/Ext.dataview.List.html#cfg-store) cannot be a string (class name), you should create it:

```
// ...
xtype: 'list',
store: Ext.create('NewsApp.store.Tasks'),
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing which you are doing wrong is calling store by `NewsApp.store.Tasks`. Which is not permissible and in result you geeting error. There are many way to achieve store in grid. One of the way which I would suggest is call by using ID.
Assign ID to your store.

```
Store :

Ext.define('NewsApp.store.Tasks', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires:[
   'NewsApp.model.Task'
] ,

alias: 'store.tasks',

model: 'NewsApp.model.Task',
id : 'NewTask',

 data : [
  {label: 'Make the bed'},
  {label: 'Go to Masjed'},
  {label: 'Take out the trash'},
  {label: 'Take Kids out'},
  {label: 'Go shopping'}
  ]});
```

and then you use this ID read store in grid.

`store : NewTask`

Please read this link to understand better. This will help you exactly the way you designing your code.[Alias](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147105-Ext.define-amp-the-alias-property)

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: does not work and still show nothing getting the same warning!

Comment: Not Sure what exactly is missing but this is also one of the way to fetch store, as I given link to justify my answer. Will get back to you if I get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Is the store loaded?
Are you using ViewModels? If so, in your viewmodel, you can set the store(s):

```
stores: {
    task: {
        //Store reference
        type: 'tasks',

        //Auto load
        autoLoad: true
    }
}
```

In this aproach, you can even bind your store to the view:

```
bind: {store: 'task'}
```